# Is there a way to make a conditional statement a variable that I can pass to a loop in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want to do something like:

```
def myfunc(p1, p2, p3):
   time_step = 0
   if p1 <= 0
      while (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0)
         stuff that updates p2, p3
         timestep+=1
   else
      while (time_step < p1)
         stuff that updates p2, p3
         timestep+=1
```

Basically, I want to be able to have the user decide if they want the while loop to run until p2 and p3 are less than or equal to 0, OR if they want the while loop to run until the desired time_step. In either case, the "stuff that updates p2, p3" is exactly the same. However, the stuff inside the while loop consists of very many lines and I would just be copying and pasting the "stuff that updates p2, p3". I feel there must be a better way.

I was hoping the following would work:

```
def myfunc(p1, p2, p3):
   time_step = 0
   if p1 <= 0
      conditional_statement = (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0)
   else
      conditional_statement = (time_step < p1)
   
   while (conditional_statement)
      stuff that updates p2, p3
      timestep+=1
```

However, I run into an infinite loop because `conditional_statement` encodes either `True` or `False`, not an actual conditional statement that would potential change each iteration.

Comment: Define another function then call that in the while conditional. `while check_conditional(p1, p2, p3):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work because `conditional_statement` is a boolean variable and will only be computed once, before the `while` loop starts. What you can do is to convert it to a function that returns a boolean (which can also be a lambda function for brevity):

```
if p1 <= 0:
    conditional_statement = lambda: (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0)
else:
    conditional_statement = lambda: (time_step < p1)
```

Then you should *call* the function object (by appending `()`) you've just created:

```
while conditional_statement():
    # Do things
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine them like this:

```
while (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0) if (p1 <= 0) else (time_step < p1):
    # Do things
```

The extra `p1 <= 0` check is more efficient than calling a function (and it could be optimized by storing the result of that check in a variable and using that instead), though in your case it sounds like the body of the loop is much heavier anyway so it doesn't matter.

A little benchmark ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLLbsMgELz7K/YSBVqr8uNSRXH/oKd@AML2ukE1GGGsKl/vLiauW6VSE4QFLDuzM6zt2Z8GUz5bN88tdvCGfTN9MJunYAv6Sn5IgIZXGsXo0UIF2RJRHdgcjnSMGWE0g2mVV4ORPSVLjxqNJ0Qvdd3KAzBbwAtkMDhiDju@QLEf8Q6STcuRJESKz5Pq8W8o4xv3Bn2sIE@SYPlVmgn7WyzHItcmwluwy2Pwxc2VyFskFLdoqM/CFkKaVlDxam3Bv/J@we5U2LlBL0HlQWk7OA8OLUqfdFREgDLgpHlHtqoO4W4yTbiJP1R6sbiuxY9q5EIrwyIlW7sc8CzPsiyFMHkKZtI1uirEOP@GW6eoxftd2YIeYQ87MgYPkGNJkEDyJISRZEhETMzn8/wF)):

```
112 ms  Selcuk
 74 ms  Manuel
 58 ms  Manuel2

112 ms  Selcuk
 73 ms  Manuel
 57 ms  Manuel2

109 ms  Selcuk
 74 ms  Manuel
 59 ms  Manuel2
```

```
def Selcuk(p1, p2, p3):
    time_step = 0
    if p1 <= 0:
        conditional_statement = lambda: (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0)
    else:
        conditional_statement = lambda: (time_step < p1)
    while conditional_statement():
        time_step += 1

def Manuel(p1, p2, p3):
    time_step = 0
    while (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0) if (p1 <= 0) else (time_step < p1):
        time_step += 1

def Manuel2(p1, p2, p3):
    time_step = 0
    by_p2_and_p3 = p1 <= 0
    while (p2 > 0 or p3 > 0) if by_p2_and_p3 else (time_step < p1):
        time_step += 1

from timeit import repeat
for _ in range(3):
    for func in Selcuk, Manuel, Manuel2:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(1000, 0, 0), number=1000))
        print('%3d ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```